# How to use DEFAULT in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I have table and function:

```
create table test_temporal (
  id SERIAL,
  name varchar(16)
);

create or replace function test_temporal_insert()
returns trigger as $$
begin
INSERT INTO test_temporal ( id, name )
values ( coalesce( new.id, DEFAULT ), new.name );
return NEW;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

But when I try to insert I get error:

```
insert into test ( name ) values ( 'a' );

ERROR:  DEFAULT is not allowed in this context
LINE 2: values ( coalesce( new.id, DEFAULT ), new.name )
                                   ^
QUERY:  INSERT INTO test_temporal ( id, name )
values ( coalesce( new.id, DEFAULT ), new.name )
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_temporal_insert() line 3 at SQL statement
```

In my trigger I need to generate next value from sequence (`DEFAULT`) if user does not provide value for `id`. If user provide value for `id` I should use it (`new.id`)

How to insert `DEFAULT` value when no `new.id` is supplied?

The [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=67cf26736fecbe7a9c6ac5bcf0513da2)

Comment: You need to add default value when creating a table.

Reference : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/ddl-default.html

Comment: @KaushikNayak: `select version(); PostgreSQL 10.4 (Debian 10.4-2.pgdg90+1)`

Comment: It's working in 10.6,  see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=62404e9a30ce1facb839ca97629d6c67) . If you remove the `coalesce`, it will compiles in older versions [9.6 demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=93dae34afe9f04e253ababd54fd4c530)

Comment: @KaushikNayak: [it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f97c234e3708dbb7d37a25bf9c411455) does not

Comment: Can you also add your trigger code?

Comment: @KaushikNayak: updated. see dbfiddle at the end

Comment: @prabinbadyakar: I have default because column type is `SERIAL`

Answer (score 0):

I resolve that via condition:

```
create or replace function test_temporal_insert()
returns trigger as $$
begin
IF( new.id is null ) THEN
  INSERT INTO test_temporal ( name )
  values ( new.name );
ELSE
  INSERT INTO test_temporal ( id, name )
  values ( new.id, new.name );
END IF;
return NEW;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

It would be much clear if Postgresql allow `coalesce( new.id, DEFAULT )`:

```
INSERT INTO test_temporal ( id, name )
values ( coalesce( new.id, DEFAULT ), new.name );
```

Comment: You can however explicitly specify default without a `coalesce` Like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e18ec300ae4556a1400dd2556e4cd8a8)

Comment: @KaushikNayak: Yes, but there still `IF THEN ELSE` block =(